# Res folder in a library project

Tags: android

I have a couple of projects that use one common library project for shared code. I'd like to be able to put layouts, strings, etc into the common project, but the compiler is not recognizing the res folders, so I can't use R. Is it possible to put layouts, etc into a library project, or am I going to have to copy them to both concrete projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to put layouts, etc into a library project

Yes. In fact, that is the point of the library project.

> I'd like to be able to put layouts, strings, etc into the common project, but the compiler is not recognizing the res folders, so I can't use R.

There is something messed up in your library project, or the project that is including the library. When you build the project that is including the library, it will resolve all `R.` references in the library's source code.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer) consisting of an Android library project with a `demo/` subproject that references and uses the library.

Comment: It looks like the child project can get at the R. references, but the common project still can't. (there are some common activities that need to use layout files) The example you attached was great, but the common activities didn't use R. (also, it doesn't look like that project works with eclipse - I couldn't import it)

Comment: @briercan: I have no idea what "common activities" are in your parlance. Here are some other Android library projects for you to examine: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-viewswiper https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist

Comment: I just recreated my lib project from scratch and it ended up working. That's the thing about eclipse. If it stops working, redo the whole thing and it'll probably start working. The info and samples you posted were very helpful. I appreciate it!

Comment: @briercan: And that's one of the many reasons I don't use Eclipse. :-) Anyway, glad to hear things are working for you.

Comment: i never got this running. accessing resources within a library project is impossible IMO.

Comment: @briercan how do use R from 'project library' in Your main app?
Do i need to import my.project.library.R in my main app? eclipse shows all class from  my.project.library but no R